# How to make the checkbox not change value

Tags: angular, checkbox, input

I have a checkbox that when i click, execute a function on angular with a validations for know if i must change the value. The problem is that although i set the variable to false, the checkbox is set to true.

Code in HTML:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" [checked]="test" [(ngModel)]="test" (click)="testClick(test)">
```

Code in component.ts:

```
public test = false;

public testClick(value) {
  value = false;
}
```

`this.test = false` in the function doesn't work.

For example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gar8xd

Althought the variable is in false, the checkbox visually change.

PD: in this code don't have the validations, only i set the value to false for test.

EDIT:
What i want is that if i set the value to false that the checkbox does not show up with the check

**SOLUTION:**

```
document.getElementById('check').checked = this.test;
```

Comment: Don't pass the `test` in `testClick(test)` instead just call the function. `test` variable should already be there in your ts file. Change that directly

Comment: All you need to do is this.test=false;

Comment: it's not an answer, but remove [checked]="test", you has [(ngModel)], so is unnecesary [checked]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event instead of `onClick`.
And set `test` to false, not `value`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7f19un

`<input type="checkbox" [checked]="test" [(ngModel)]="test" (change)="testClick(test)">`

```
public testClick(value) {
  this.test = false;
}
```

Comment: But althought the variable is in false, the checkbox show up with the check. What i want is that the variable is in false, the checkbox show up without the check.

Comment: I think this is the normal behavior of a checkbox, and you can't change it

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not setting the test variable to the value coming in testClick(test) method, instead you're hardcoding the value coming in the method as false. Just do this in `testClick(test)` method in ts file and you're good to go - `this.test = value;`

working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaqua6

Comment: But althought the variable is in false, the checkbox show up with the check. What i want is that the variable is in false, the checkbox show up without the check.

Comment: no, it doesn't, please check again. Initially variable is false and checkbox is unchecked, when you're clicking on checkbox it's changing the variable to true.

Comment: @jdflores if the provided solution is working for you, accept this as answer to your question. If you want anything else, provide clear requirements so that users can understand in a better way and help you